# linum-off for nlinum

Tags: linum-mode

Many people are advertising nlinum over linum. I had a configuration for linum copied from the linum-off.el script you can find on internet:

```
(require 'linum)

(defcustom linum-disabled-modes-list '(eshell-mode wl-summary-mode compilation-mode org-mode text-mode dired-mode doc-view-mode image-mode)
  "* List of modes disabled when global linum mode is on"
  :type '(repeat (sexp :tag "Major mode"))
  :tag " Major modes where linum is disabled: "
  :group 'linum
)
(defcustom linum-disable-starred-buffers 't
  "* Disable buffers that have stars in them like *Gnu Emacs*"
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'linum)

(defun linum-on ()
  "* When linum is running globally, disable line number in modes defined in `linum-disabled-modes-list'. Changed by linum-off. Also turns off numbering in starred modes like *scratch*"

  (unless (or (minibufferp)
              (member major-mode linum-disabled-modes-list)
              (string-match "*" (buffer-name))
              (> (buffer-size) 3000000)) ;; disable linum on buffer greater than 3MB, otherwise it's unbearably slow
    (linum-mode 1)))

(provide 'linum-off)
```

I wonder if it is possible to achieve the same thing with nlinum, knowing that there is no nlinum-on function to override. I am mostly interesting by this because I want to disable nlinum for the buffers starting with a * and for a few very specific files/buffers.